# Pandas - Error inserting text column into Redshift table

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-redshift, psycopg2

I am trying to insert a text column of into a Redshift DB.

I get an error

```
DataError: value too long for type character varying(256)
```

Given below is the code I tried. The description column has text and the length goes upto 2000 characters.

Could anyone assist on how I could have this column inserted into the table.

```
 DF['description'] = DF['description'].str[:200].astype(str)
```

Could anyone assist, thanks.

Comment: probably extended character set, try increasing it to 400 and see if that works

Comment: @JonScott, it throws an error when I try with 200 characters itself.

Comment: did you try what i suggested? increase the TARGET to 400 (or maybe more) but leave the source the same (ie 200)

Comment: @JonScott,  the below worked for me.  DF['description'] = DF['description'].str.slice(0,250). Tried increasing the column length to be 300 but it threw the same error..

Answer (score 0):

You should be using `str.slice`.

`df['description'] = df['description'].str.slice(0,255)`

Please note that this function works only in case of `Strings` or you may have to typecast.

Hope it helps.

Comment: `df['description'] = df['description'].str.slice(0,254)` if it doesn't work, I have read it in some other question that size was 2 but `Redshift` was expecting one additional character length, though I don't believe should be the case.

Comment: sorry for the late reply. Tried the above suggestion but it threw the same error even when I tried str.slice(0,250).