# Redshift - Issue inserting text column to Database table

Tags: amazon-redshift, psycopg2, python-jira

I am trying to update data from JIRA to Redshift DB using python. I am having issues updating value from 'description' column. The target column in DB is of type varchar.

Given below is how I modify the 'description' column before inserting it into Redshift DB.

```
df['description'] = df['description'].astype(str)
```

And it throws the below error:

```
DataError: value too long for type character varying(256)
```

Is there anything wrong that I am doing to have this field inserted. Length of values in the description column go upto 6000 characters.

Any help on this, would be appreciated..

Answer (score 0):

Probably duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51175273/pandas-error-inserting-text-column-into-redshift-table).

`df['description'] = df['description'].str.slice(0,255)`

**EDIT AFTER COMMENT**
Here is my fully working example.

```
import pandas as pd

d = {'name' : pd.Series(['FFFFF', 'FFFFF', 'FFFFFGGGGg'], index=['a', 'b', 'c']),
     'description' : pd.Series(['FFFFF', 'FFFFF', 'FFFFFGGGGg','4666666666'], index=['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']),
     'place' : pd.Series(['166666660', '26666666660', '3666666660'], index=['a', 'b', 'c'])}

df = pd.DataFrame(d)
print ("Our dataframe is:")
print (df)

print ("Modifying column description:")

df['description'] = df['description'].str.slice(0,4)
print(df)
```

Comment: thanks for the reply. Tried using your suggestion "df['description'].str.slice(0,255)". It throws an error "ProgrammingError: can't adapt type 'dict'".

Comment: Not sure why you are getting an exception, I have just added my full working example, which one of line I shared earlier. Hope it helps.

Comment: I think, can't adapt might be because of datatype mismatch, though not sure.

Comment: Wondering how to address this since my source column length is more than 256 characters but the target column type is varchar. Believe this is causing an issue..

Comment: `str.slice(0,4)` is converting orignal length to 4 characters, similarly (0,255) will truncate from any length to 255 character.